# give an initial value to the type File in flutter

Tags: flutter

hi every one I need to give an initial value to the type File in flutter language such as this var File _profileImage = ; what I should put after the = . **I don't want use this format File? _profileImage;**

Comment: `File? _profileImage=null;` then in your image widget  `_profileimage == null ? Icon(Icons.man) : Image.file(_profileimage)`

Answer (score 0):

A `File` object doesn't *do* anything until you perform an operation on it (such as trying to open, read from, or write to the underlying file on the filesystem).  Therefore, if you really want, you could do `var _profileImage = File('');` and check `_profileImage.path.isNotEmpty` everywhere later. (For POSIX systems, you also could consider `File('/dev/null')`, which wouldn't fail if you attempt to read from or write to it.)

However, that is arguably not any better than using `File?` with a `null` default.  Using a `File?` would allow Dart's type system to catch any places where you neglect to check for that bogus initial value at compile-time.